# how to submit clone form with JQuery in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

Need help understanding how can i submit clone form in JavaScript?

I'll use Tristan Denyer's clone form to explain my question. Here's a link to Tristan's dynamic form:

http://tristandenyer.com/demos/dynamic-form-bootstrap-3-0.html

You'll see in the demo from the link above that the entire form are being "cloned" or duplicated when the "add section" button is clicked.

Question is, how do you submit each form individually when the "submit" button is click.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
-crianne

Comment: Those demo form did't duplicated. Only children and descendants was cloned. In your case, just get the parent form and register submit event into it.

Comment: But how can you treat each clone  as if its it own form. Cause what i'm trying to achieve is submit each clone in my server. So basically each clone is a single entry/submission in the database

Comment: So basically, each `form` have it own `submit button`? And if pressing `submit button` on form number 2 as example, then only send its element?

Comment: There's only one submit button. It just that when the submit button is click, each set of field(e.i. In the demo, each 'Entry' has set of inputs. So basically i'd like to treat each 'Entry as a form and push it in the database as a single entry. For instance, in the demo when a user click 'add section' and click submit then there will be 2 entry/submission to my database

Comment: Guess you need to make first set element name as an array name. As example `first_name` would be `first_name[]`. What server side language you're using right now?

Comment: I'm using Google App Script environment. So i'm using Javascript to pass the form values to a Javascript server side